# Does Azure offer Batch translations ? I've exhausted their documentation

Tags: python, azure, translation, batch-processing, speech-to-text

I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on my issue.

I need to do a batch translation of audio files to text, translating this from one language to another.

I have been looking at the documentation (the below url for hours) and their is no indication on how this can be done.

So far I have been using the "continuous" translations call for each audio file.

Is batch translation possible ?

Much appreciated,
D

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/console/translation_sample.py

Answer (score 0):

> Does Azure offer Batch translations?

Yes, Azure offers the Batch Translations as mentioned here in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription).

We can use the `Speech to text v3.0 Rest API` to translate the audio files by using the below code which was mentioned in the above link:

```
{
  "contentUrls": [
    "<URL to an audio file 1 to transcribe>",
    "<URL to an audio file 2 to transcribe>",
    "<URL to an audio file 3 to transcribe>"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "wordLevelTimestampsEnabled": true
  },
  "locale": "en-US",
  "displayName": "Transcription of file using default model for en-US"
}
```

We need to pass this `json` file to the **V3 Rest Api** for translation of audio files.

Also refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/document-translation/get-started-with-document-translation?tabs=csharp) for document translation.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. It does offer transcription but not translations. I have looked at the documentation link and it does not mention it their. I'm I missing something ?

Comment: The document you shared is text-to-text translation and speech-to-text translations for batching - example code link is here  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/console/translation_sample.py